# como configurar con thymeleaf un input type number para tener serparador de decimales con una coma y separador de miles con un punto

Tags: mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

como configurar con thymeleaf un input type number para tener serparador de decimales con una coma y separador de miles con un punto,lo he intentado de muchas maneras y no me funciona, agradezco mucho la ayuda que puedan prestarme mas abajo esta el codigo

```
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control   " name="salario"  required
                                th:field="*{salario}" th:errorClass="is-invalid">
                            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('salario')}" th:errors="*{salario}"
                                class="invalid-feedback">
                            </td>
```